# How to run javascipt on chrome console

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools

Hello I want to try to run all of these code on console chrome

```
var xxx = document.querySelectorAll('.balanceDetails-manageCurrencies.test_mcm-addCurrency')
xxx.forEach(btn => btn.click())
var twd = document.querySelectorAll('.shadow.multiCurrency-flag.multiCurrency-flag_TWD')
twd.forEach(btn => btn.click())
var addcurrency = document.querySelectorAll('.btn.vx_btn.mandate_lg-btn.test_mcm-addCurrencyButton')
addcurrency.forEach(btn => btn.click())
```

But it doesnt run everything, the process just stop when they excute line number 2

```
xxx.forEach(btn => btn.click())
```

Question is, how to run all of these code?

Comment: Have you checked out this documentation page yet? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities

Comment: well does the button refresh the page or submit a form? My guess is the click does something and stops the code

Comment: @epascarello yesss! right, they refresh to submit form

Comment: @epascarello do you know how to handle this?

Comment: Well it is not going to happen in the console. You are really using the wrong tool if you want to automate something. You want to look into Selenium.

Comment: @epascarello So the console is can't use this one? Yes i want to do automate something on form. So what should I use? Except imacros or UI.vison (Kantu)

Comment: Problem is with console, it is just like code being on the page. So when the page exits, so does the console. I would use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-ide/mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd or Selenium WebDriver

Answer (score 0):

Try combining the arrays then running the click loop on the new array.

replace sel1 etc to your selectors

```
var xxx = [...document.querySelectorAll(sel1), ...document.querySelectorAll(sel2), ...document.querySelectorAll(sel3)]
xxx.forEach(el => el.click())
```

Comment: Seems its work, but again it just run the first array. Because the PAGE is need to load array 1 to next step on array 2. Hope you understand what i mean

Comment: Are you sure the elements in sel2 are visible/clickable?

Comment: No, when I run the array 1 they load new website / load another html code. But the website is same. They just redirect to a LIST of CURRENCIES and Array 2 is SELECT the CURRENCIES, Array 3 is CONFIRM

Comment: Then you'll need to run your original commands but add a setTImeout before the next lines to make sure the next elements are there and ready to be clicked

Comment: And what the code i had to use to add setTimeout? I put that after the first one action right?

Comment: Yes, thank's its worked! I just need to add this 

console.log(setTimeout(() => console.log('a'), 3000));

And then the second and third function will run without error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what's going on in your case because we don't know what your selected DOM nodes are doing after being clicked. If you paste that entire code block into the chrome console I would expect it to execute all of it.

Two things off the top of my head could be happening.

1. The click handler setup to fire on one of those DOM nodes is throwing an error, but that error is being caught by a try/catch block and never bubbles up to the console. This would create the symptoms described.
2. The click handler for one of those DOM nodes is doing a form post, or something else that will cause the page to reload. Although, if this were the case you'd see the console clear. Not sure if you're seeing that or not.

Comment: What i selected is The First one Add a New currencies on Paypal, The Second one Is Selected Spesific Currencies, The Third one is Confirm

Yes when i do the first one, they reload a new AJAX or something like LIST of the currencies, and yes they redirect to another page but it AJAX. I just had to selected which currencies i want.